# Eclipse "Failed to create the part's controls" InlinedAnnotationSupport

Tags: eclipse, lombok, myeclipse

I'm using MyEclipse and when I open a Java class that's not in a project but in a library somewhere, I get a `Failed to create the part's controls` error message, and this stack trace:
Abbreviated trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.inlined.InlinedAnnotationSupport$VisibleLines.install(InlinedAnnotationSupport.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.inlined.InlinedAnnotationSupport$VisibleLines.<init>(InlinedAnnotationSupport.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.inlined.InlinedAnnotationSupport.install(InlinedAnnotationSupport.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.ensureCodeMiningManagerInstalled(SourceViewer.java:1295)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.setCodeMiningAnnotationPainter(SourceViewer.java:1320)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.SourceViewerDecorationSupport.showAnnotations(SourceViewerDecorationSupport.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.SourceViewerDecorationSupport.updateTextDecorations(SourceViewerDecorationSupport.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.SourceViewerDecorationSupport.install(SourceViewerDecorationSupport.java:269)
```

Full picture

[image]

The only thing I've added to this is Lombok annotations.

Comment: Looks to be related to code mining. You could try turning that off - "Java > Editor > Coding Mining" in the Preferences.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the tip but it didn't make a fix the problem.